# List within a list - python

Tags: python, list

I have a list within a list.

Within a sublist if two conditions are met - the first element is TRUE and second element is TRUE - then the third element from that sublist should be printed.

I have managed to create this code for one of the sublists by using an index but how do i get the code to check ALL the sublists and print the third element of those lists?

```
mylist =[['TRUE', 'TRUE', 'SKU001'], ['FALSE', 'TRUE', 'SKU002'], ['TRUE', 'FALSE', 'SKU003'], ['FALSE', 'TRUE', 'SKU004']]

if (mylist[0][0]) == 'TRUE' and (mylist[0][1]) == 'TRUE':
    print(mylist[0][1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
mylist =[['TRUE', 'TRUE', 'SKU001'], ['FALSE', 'TRUE', 'SKU002'], ['TRUE', 'FALSE', 'SKU003'], ['FALSE', 'TRUE', 'SKU004']]

for i in mylist:
    if (i[0]) == 'TRUE' and (i[1]) == 'TRUE':
        print(i[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, check if `False` exists then skip.

```
print([x[-1] for x in mylist if 'FALSE' not in x[0:2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop you can iterate through all lists in your main list

```py
allLists =[['TRUE', 'TRUE', 'SKU001'], ['FALSE', 'TRUE', 'SKU002'], ['TRUE', 'FALSE', 'SKU003'], ['FALSE', 'TRUE', 'SKU004'], ['TRUE', 'TRUE', 'SKU005']]

for myList in allLists:
    if (myList[0] == 'TRUE' and myList[1] == 'TRUE'):
        print(myList[2])
```